# Как при нажатии на кнопку срабатывало несколько функций. PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

Только начинаю работать с PyQt5, поэтому многое не понимаю. Для приложения необходимо при нажатии на кнопку срабатывание нескольких функций, закрытие элементов и открытие необходимых по другой функции. Метод ***clicked.connect*** может принимать только 1 аргумент, поэтому не знаю как решить проблему.

```
class untitled(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    #Присоединение окна
    super().__init__()
    self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)

    self.ui.goin.clicked.connect(self.ui.closed)
    self.ui.goin_2.clicked.connect(self.ui.closed)
```

Вот второй файл с функциями:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class Ui_Dialog(object):
def setupUi(self, Dialog):

    #Работа с окном
    Dialog.setFixedSize(800, 500)
    palette = QtGui.QPalette()
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Background, QtCore.Qt.white)
    Dialog.setPalette(palette)
    Dialog.setWindowTitle("Synaptik")

    font = QtGui.QFont()

    #Текст авторизации
    self.autorithetion = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
    self.autorithetion.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 60, 300, 50))
    font.setFamily("Candara Light")
    font.setPointSize(35)
    self.autorithetion.setFont(font)
    self.autorithetion.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);")

    #Кнопка Входа
    self.goin = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
    self.goin.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 250, 200, 40))
    font.setFamily("Candara Light")
    font.setPointSize(16)
    self.goin.setFont(font)

    # Кнопка Регистрации
    self.goin_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
    self.goin_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 310, 200, 40))
    font.setFamily("Candara Light")
    font.setPointSize(16)
    self.goin_2.setFont(font)

    #Установка текста
    self.autorithetion.setText("Авторизация")
    self.goin.setText("Войти")
    self.goin_2.setText("Зарегистрироваться")

def closed(self):
    self.goin.close()
    self.goin_2.close()
    self.autorithetion.close()

def openned_1(self):
    self.autorithetion.show()
```

Comment: а что если все функции которые нужно вызывать прописать в одной функции и вызывать только её в clicked.connect

Comment: У меня по функции closed скрываются все элементы, а по функции opened открываются необходимые, и если я впишу все в одну то придется делать для каждой кнопки отдельные функции.

Comment: пожалуйста. опубликуйте ваш модуль, который вы получили после конвертации формы созданной в 
Qt Designer и который содержит класс `Ui_Dialog`.

Comment: @S.Nick , я сделал правку, теперь можете посмотреть.

Comment: Позволю себе дать вам некоторые советы. 1. `НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ код, сгенерированный Qt Designer, НИКОГДА`. Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения. 2. Еще раз прочитайте второе предложение в 1п. Это означает что если создали форму в Qt Designer наследуясь от `QDialog`, то и при создании класса  untitled надо писать `class untitled(QtWidgets.QDialog):`. 3. Название классов всегда пишется с заглавной буквы... `Untitled`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял-то попробуйте в `lambda` записать функции которые вы вызываете через кому вот таким вот образом

```
self.ui.goin.clicked.connect(lambda : (self.ui.closed, self.ui.openned_1))
```

или создать отдельную функцию которая будет вызывать остальные функции

```
def show():
    self.ui.closed()
    self.ui.openned_1()
self.ui.goin.clicked.connect(self.show)
```

Comment: В ваших обоих предложениях присутствуют ошибки. Пожалуйста исправьте их.